# Matcher returning not match

Tags: java, regex

i'v tested my regex on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pG1qS8/1) and all the groups was captured and matched my string. But now when i'm trying to use it on java, it returns to me a

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found on line 9

```
   String subjectCode = "02 credits between ----";
   String regex1 = "^(\\d+).*credits between --+.*?$";       
   Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(regex1);
   Matcher m;

  if(subjectCode.matches(regex1)){
    m = p1.matcher(regex1);
    m.find();
    [LINE 9]Integer subjectCredits = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
      System.out.println("Subject Credits: " + subjectCredits);
  }
```

How's that possible and what's the problem?

Comment: Your code won't magically translate itself

Comment: My bad, i didnt see it. Now its translated. @cricket_007

Comment: You might want to try `m = p1.matcher(subjectCode)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fix and optimizations (thanks go to [@cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007)):

```
String subjectCode = "02 credits between ----";
String regex1 = "(\\d+).*credits between --+.*";
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(regex1);
Matcher m = p1.matcher(subjectCode);
if (m.matches()) {
    Integer subjectCredits = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
    System.out.println("Subject Credits: " + subjectCredits);
}
```

You need to pass the input string to the `matcher`. As a minor enhancement, you can use just 1 `Matcher#matches` and then access the captured group if there is a match. The regex does not need `^` and `$` since with `matches()` the whole input should match the pattern.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/SDoDUF)

Comment: Why did you compile the pattern twice?

Comment: I have just found out that the only pertinent change is passing the string to the matcher :)

Comment: You could still get rid of the outer if statement entirely, actually.

Comment: Ah, you are checking if I went to bed, aren't you? Right you are. Updated.